# Why can I only set mat-elevation settings at the component level css?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, scss-mixins, mat-card

I am using Angular material in my Angular 8 project and am trying to set up the design of the shadow on my material cards. I am using the elevation helper mixins as described here: https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation

Rather than customise these elevations in the css file of each component, I am trying to do it at a global level. When I declare the styling class at the component level it works, but when I declare it at a global level only SOME of the css works.

**When I declare the class in the global styles.css file**

```
// styles.scss
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

.card-design {
   border: 1px solid #ff0000; // this IS applied
   @include mat-elevation(8); // this is NOT applied
}
```

**When I declare the class at the component level**

```
// nameOfComponent.component.scss
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

.card-design {
   border: 1px solid #ff0000; // this IS applied
   @include mat-elevation(8); // this IS applied
}
```

Since the border color IS being applied when I declare the class at the global level I therefore know the class is being applied correctly, its just that the elevation is either not being applied or it is being overwritten.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:host` or/and `::ng-deep` like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .card-design {
   border: 1px solid #ff0000; // this IS applied
   @include mat-elevation(8); // this is NOT applied
}
```

or

```
:host .card-design {
   border: 1px solid #ff0000; // this IS applied
   @include mat-elevation(8); // this is NOT applied
}
```

Reed more about host [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host). 
Looks like the ::nd-deep has been deprecated [link](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

I've not tested it, but this should work since I encounter similar problems while working with `Angular 7`.